# Mapping Rest Services GIS API on Aptana 3 webpage not implementing

Tags: api, rest, service, aptana, arcgis

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 to create a map, I replaced the function init address to the appropriate address needed to link to the map I want to represent. When I Run it on Aptana Studio 3, it brings me to an unfinished build where the map isn't present and only an outline of the Map Area, plus instructional use on the bottom. I tried using other samples from the ArcGIS resource center to only get the same results if I implement it through Aptana or through Root Directory.

> Create Map
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.2"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   dojo.require("esri.map");
>
>   function init() {
>     var map = new esri.Map("map");
>
>     var imageParameters = new esri.layers.ImageParameters();
>     imageParameters.format = "jpeg";  //set the image type to PNG24, note default is PNG8.
>     //Takes a URL to a non cached map service.
>     var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://maps.nbtexas.org/ArcGIS/rest/services/Maps/NewBraunfelsBaseMap/MapServer",
> ```
>
> {"opacity":0.5, "imageParameters":imageParameters});
>           map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer);
>         }
>
> ```
>   dojo.addOnLoad(init);
> </script>   </head>   <body class="claro">
> <div id="map" style="width:900px; height:600px; border:1px solid #000;"></div>
> Creates a map and adds an ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer.<br />
> Map navigation using mouse:
> <ul>
>   <li>Drag to pan</li>
>   <li>SHIFT + Click to recenter</li>
>   <li>SHIFT + Drag to zoom in</li>
>   <li>SHIFT + CTRL + Drag to zoom out</li>
>   <li>Mouse Scroll Forward to zoom in</li>
>   <li>Mouse Scroll Backward to zoom out</li>
>   <li>Use Arrow keys to pan</li>
>   <li>+ key to zoom in a level</li>
>   <li>- key to zoom out a level</li>
>   <li>Double Click to Center and Zoom in</li>
> </ul>   </body> </html>
> ```